# Why does my exception prevent code from running

Tags: oracle, plsql, oraclereports

I'm a trainee developer who has been put in charge of other people's code so most of my work will be modifying their work. I'm using Report builder on Oracle 10g.

I have the following setup in a formula:

```
function get_addressFormula return Char is
begin
if :payee_ctc_id is not null then
begin
 select  a.address
        ,a.address2
        ,a.address3
        ,g.location
            ,g.ppostcode
 into    :address1
        ,:address2
        ,:address3
        ,:address4
        ,:postcode

 from ctc_address a
     ,geo_locations g

 where a.addresstypeid = 1  
 and   a.costcentreid = :payee_ctc_id
 and   g.locationid = a.locationid
 and   a.addressid = (select max(i.addressid)   
                      from  ctc_address i
            where i.costcentreid = :payee_ctc_id
            and   i.addresstypeid = 1);

exception
    when others then
      return null;

    while trim(:address1) is null and (trim(:address2) is not null or trim(:address2)  is not null or trim(:address4) is not null)
    loop
      :address1 := :address2; 
      :address2 := :address3; 
      :address3 := :address4; 
      :address4 := '';
    end loop;

    while trim(:address2) is null and (trim(:address3) is not null or trim(:address4) is not null)
    loop
      :address2 := :address3; 
      :address3 := :address4; 
      :address4 := '';
    end loop;

    while trim(:address3) is null and trim(:address4) is not null
    loop
      :address3 := :address4; 
      :address4 := '';
    end loop;

end;
else
 begin
  <else code>
 end;
 end if;

return 'y';
end;
```

This is the full function except for the last else block. I tried no_data_found but still doesn't work.

@tbone. I'm not sure how to do that. I did some Googling on RAISE with little luck so far.

Comment: you might want to actually raise the exception instead of trapping it and returning null (which is why you don't know what the heck happened).

Comment: Can you show us more code and point out the code that is not executed? If the code after `EXCEPTION` is never executed, it means that the exception is always thrown and the block ends with `RETURN NULL`

Comment: It's hard to comment on this as some important syntax has been removed from your example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Block structure](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/overview.htm#i8859):

> ```
> << label >> (optional)
> DECLARE    -- Declarative part (optional)
>   -- Declarations of local types, variables, & subprograms
>
> BEGIN      -- Executable part (required)
>   -- Statements (which can use items declared in declarative part)
>
> [EXCEPTION -- Exception-handling part (optional)
>   -- Exception handlers for exceptions (errors) raised in executable part]
> END;
> ```

You need a `BEGIN/END` for each `EXCEPTION`:

```
if :payee_id is not null then    
   begin
      <Select statement which place results into placeholders>
   exception
      when NO_DATA_FOUND then
         return null;
   end;
   <code>    
else
   <else code>
end if;
```

Also note that the use of `WHEN OTHERS` not followed by a `RAISE` is a bad [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). You don't want to ignore ALL errors, so be specific. Usually you only want to catch a `NO_DATA_FOUND`.

Comment: Thanks Vincent. Can you please show me how to use RAISE? As mentioned about NO_DATA_FOUND doesn't work either. I wrote a modified version in Toad and trying different things in there. No luck yet. I will scratch around in our other procs for RAISE examples.

Comment: @arend in your example it makes no sense to have code after the `RETURN NULL`: this code will never be run. A block is defined by a `BEGIN/END` so your `END` should probably be after the `RETURN NULL` instead of before the `ELSE`.

Comment: You can use [`raise_application_error`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/errors.htm#i1871) to raise an exception. But in most cases if you're not logging the error you'd better not use `WHEN OTHERS`. Let the unknown error propagate, there is no point in catching unexpected exceptions.

Comment: I did what I should've tried first. I moved the exception block to just above the end statement. I tested it with valid and invalid values and it works fine. Thanks!